# what does angle brackets mean in documentation?

Tags: git, documentation, code-documentation

little did i know. that square brackets `[option]` are used to indicate a parameter that is optional. such as `function(param1 [, param2])` which indicate that `param1` is required and `param2` is optional.

but what about angle brackets `<something>` and `--` mean in documentation? such as;

`git config [<file-option>] [--type=<type>] --add name value`

and what does `--type=<type>` mean?

*thank you for your answers*

Answer (score 2):

Angle brackets or italics indicate identifier/parameter/argument values that are provided by users.